# How to dynamically call a variable based on another variable in java

Tags: java, variables

I have an assignment and to simplify the code I would like to be able to reference a String based on the value of an int.

```
//Below is a rough example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

String player1Piece = "x";
String player2Piece = "O";
int playerturn; //Assigned value of either 1 or 2 later in code.
...
System.out.println(player(playerturn)Piece);
```

Let me know if this is at all possible but if not my current solution would be to use a switch statement and just copy and paste the output code.

Comment: Sounds like you need an array of strings instead of 2 separate strings....

Comment: what a wonderful idea. Thanks!

Comment: The other common tool for this sort of thing is a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a compiled language, and does not have an `eval` function. You **could** use a simple `if - else` like

```
if (playerturn == 1) {
    System.out.println(player1Piece);
} else {
    System.out.println(player2Piece);
}
```

**or** you could store the pieces in an array, and access the array by index. Like,

```
String[] pieces = { "X", "O" };
// ...
System.out.println(pieces[playerturn - 1]);
```

**note** that arrays are indexed from `0` (so `playerturn - 1` is necessary if you want to use the values `1` and `2`).

**or** you could store the pieces in a map, and access the map by key. Like,

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "X");
map.put(2, "O");
// ...
System.out.println(map.get(playerturn));
```

**note** that with a `Map` the `playerturn` value can be used without modification.